# Can I use MATLAB editor without running MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, editor

Is there any way to open MATLAB editor without opening MATLAB ? I would like to edit my codes using MATLAB editor and my laptop is getting very slow. So Can I just open MATLAB editor?

Also, is there any good editor like MATLAB's editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MATLAB Editor is part of the IDE, so you can't launch it without launching MATLAB.

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a great text editor for Windows, that supports syntax highlighting for many languages, including MATLAB, and is pretty lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

You can just open it in notepad or text editor. Just right click on it and select open with and then select whichever text editor you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Since MATLAB GUI is quite computationally expensive I open MATLAB without the GUI:

```
matlab -nodesktop
```

In such a way I have the MATLAB prompt ready to work and I edit files with sublime text editor setting MATLAB syntax.

It looks like this:
[image]